# Render the User model relationship field on Django template

Tags: django

it was supposed to be simple but I'm not able to solve it so far. I got a Profile model which is a OneToOneField with the User model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                related_name='profile',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    rua = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    bairro = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    complemento = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    cidade = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    cep = models.CharField(max_length=9)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rua
```

What I'm trying to do is render some Profile fields on Django template using the {{ user.profile.rua }} but it's not working.

Any help?

Thank you!

EDIT:

My view:

```
def checkout(request):

    return render(request, 'payment/checkout.html')
```

Comment: add your view as well as your relevant template code

Comment: Arakkal, I added my view. I tried to call the {{ user.profile.rua }} on the Django template. It's weird because if I only code {{ user.username }} the user's name is displayed correctly.

Comment: are you sure that the user has a `Profile` instance in the database? What do you see if you call `print(request.user.profile.rua)` in your *view*?

Comment: Arakkal, I'm really sorry! You caught me... This user in specific has not been recorded yet in the Profile model - it's all empty!